netplan 2nd if ip address
i have 2 ethernet devices, i setup one which is working which also includes default gateway. Now i want to add a 2nd segment and i made setup in netplan regarding docu.
netplann generate neither netplan apply croaks in debug mode for any failure, but the 2nd ip address does not appear on the interface. (which is actually not connected)
yaml file:
network:
ethernets:
    enp1s0:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
    enp2s0:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.63.251/24
        nameservers:
         search: [domain.tld]
         addresses: [192.168.63.1, 192.168.63.254]
        routes:
          - to: default
            via: 192.168.63.254
   version: 2

but ip address for enp1s0 is not set
enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:d0:b4:02:40:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0x80e00000-80efffff

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.63.251  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.63.255
    inet6 fe80::2d0:b4ff:fe02:4025  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:d0:b4:02:40:25  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1888295  bytes 1372768091 (1.3 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 224009  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 498157  bytes 136051635 (136.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0x80b00000-80bfffff

Did i missed an entry ?
Ciaso Gerd

You mention that enp1s0 is not actually connected, that's probably why it won't be configured by Netplan+systemd-networkd.
Try adding an ethernets.enp1s0.ignore-carrier: true setting, e.g.:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.2/24
       ignore-carrier: true
    enp2s0:
      [...]

